# Express with Firebase require() throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express

I have an Express application that I am trying to connect to Firebase.

My console is currently throwing this error:

```
C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Dev\food-bank\app.cjs:19
const firebase = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
                 ^

TypeError: initializeApp is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tyler\Desktop\Dev\food-bank\app.cjs:19:18)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1095:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

The offending code is here:

```
let initializeApp = require('./node_modules/@firebase/app');
```

I don't want to change my `package.json` to use import statements. The Firebase docs have import module statements but because I'm using Express I want to use the `require` statements.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're simply missing the destructuring brackets in the require statement:

```
let { initializeApp } = require('./node_modules/@firebase/app');
```

Also, normally you should simply be able to `require('@firebase/app')` and not specify the relative path to packages inside `node_modules`:

```
    let { initializeApp } = require('@firebase/app');
```